# How can i filter out rows where the difference is less than a threshold?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, function, filter

**The problem and context:**

I am working with electronic equipment, which records events measured using a reed switch. It records the time that the reed switch opens (recorded as 0) and closes (recorded as 1). This equipment sometimes records false measurements at timescales we know are not realistic. The 'default state' of the device is normally closed.

**What I am trying to do:**

Filter out the changes in state, where the time difference is less than 60 seconds. But...often times there are a bunch of false openings and closings following each other. Additionally, the resulting dataframe must have events ordered as 1,0,1,0,1 etc - the device can only open, then close, then open etc.

**What I have tried:**

I have got some code working, but it's long and messy. I am sure there must be a better way of doing this. Any suggestions would be great.

**Example original dataframe**

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'date' : ['2019-05-10 12:20:31', '2019-05-10 12:25:43', '2019-05-10 12:25:57', '2019-05-10 12:28:00', '2019-05-10 12:30:01', '2019-05-10 12:35:00', '2019-05-10 12:35:30', '2019-05-10 12:35:45', '2019-05-10 12:37:00', '2019-05-10 12:40:00', '2019-05-10 12:45:00'], 'event' : [1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1]}, index=range(11))

df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'], errors='raise', dayfirst=True)
df['event'] = pd.to_numeric(df['event'])
```

```
df
Out[21]: 
                  date  event
0  2019-05-10 12:20:31      1
1  2019-05-10 12:25:43      0
2  2019-05-10 12:25:57      1
3  2019-05-10 12:28:00      0
4  2019-05-10 12:30:01      1
5  2019-05-10 12:35:00      0
6  2019-05-10 12:35:30      1
7  2019-05-10 12:35:45      0
8  2019-05-10 12:37:00      1
9  2019-05-10 12:40:00      0
10 2019-05-10 12:45:00      1
```

**Functions created**

```
def filter_event_filter_dups(input_data, input_variable_name):
    """
    This is an 'inside' function for the main filter_event function and iteratively removes duplicates

    """
    df_tmp = input_data.copy()
    df_tmp = df_tmp.dropna()
    df_tmp = df_tmp.reset_index()
    df_tmp_final = pd.DataFrame(columns=['date', input_variable_name], index=range(len(df_tmp)))
    for index, row in df_tmp.iterrows():
        if index == 0:
            print('')
            df_tmp_final['date'].loc[index] = df_tmp['date'].loc[index]
            df_tmp_final[input_variable_name].loc[index] = df_tmp[input_variable_name].loc[index]
        else:
            if index + 1 == len(df_tmp):
                print('---------------------------------------------------------------')
                print('Index = ', index)
                print('End!')
            else:
                print('---------------------------------------------------------------')
                print('Index = ', index)
                
                if df_tmp[input_variable_name].loc[index] == df_tmp[input_variable_name].loc[index-1]:
                    # keep only first
                    # delete second
                    # df_tmp = df_tmp.drop([df_tmp.loc[index+1]])
                    df_tmp_final['date'].loc[index-1] = df_tmp['date'].loc[index-1]
                    df_tmp_final[input_variable_name].loc[index-1] = df_tmp[input_variable_name].loc[index-1]
                elif df_tmp[input_variable_name].loc[index] != df_tmp[input_variable_name].loc[index-1]:
                    df_tmp_final['date'].loc[index] = df_tmp['date'].loc[index]
                    df_tmp_final[input_variable_name].loc[index] = df_tmp[input_variable_name].loc[index]
    return(df_tmp_final)


def filter_event(input_data, input_variable_name, input_delta_time_threshold_seconds):
    """
    This function is designed to filer out events which are very close together.
    """
    df_tmp = input_data.reset_index()
    df_tmp[input_variable_name] = pd.to_numeric(df_tmp[input_variable_name])
    del df_tmp['index']
    # output_df = pd.DataFrame()
    output_df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['date', input_variable_name], index=range(len(df_tmp)))
    for index, row in df_tmp.iterrows():
        if index+1 == len(df_tmp):
            print('---------------------------------------------------------------')
            print('Index = ', index)
            print('End!')
        else:
            # if df_tmp[input_variable_name].loc[index] == 0:
            print('---------------------------------------------------------------')
            print('Index = ', index)
            if ((df_tmp['date'].iloc[index+1] - df_tmp['date'].iloc[index]).total_seconds())<input_delta_time_threshold_seconds:
                # If less than threshold
                print('This is LESS than threshold - Threshold = ', input_delta_time_threshold_seconds, 'seconds')
                print('Time difference to next 0 = ', df_tmp['date'].loc[index+1]-df_tmp['date'].loc[index])
                print('Ignore')
            if ((df_tmp['date'].iloc[index+1] - df_tmp['date'].iloc[index]).total_seconds())>input_delta_time_threshold_seconds:
                # If more than threshold
                print('This is MORE than threshold - Threshold = ', input_delta_time_threshold_seconds, 'seconds') 
                print('Time difference to next 0 = ', df_tmp['date'].loc[index+1]-df_tmp['date'].loc[index])
                output_df['date'].loc[index] = df_tmp['date'].loc[index]
                output_df[input_variable_name].loc[index] = df_tmp[input_variable_name].loc[index]
                # output_df['date'].loc[index+1] = df_tmp['date'].loc[index+1]
                # output_df[input_variable_name].loc[index+1] = df_tmp[input_variable_name].loc[index+1]
    output_df = output_df.dropna()
    output_df = output_df.reset_index()
    
    output_df[input_variable_name] = pd.to_numeric(output_df[input_variable_name])
    #
    #
    #
    output_df_final = filter_event_filter_dups(input_data = output_df, input_variable_name = input_variable_name)
    
    # for i in range(2):
    #     output_df_final = filter_event_filter_dups(input_data = output_df_final, input_variable_name = input_variable_name)
    
    output_df_final = output_df_final.dropna()
    output_df_final[input_variable_name] = pd.to_numeric(output_df_final[input_variable_name])
    # output_df_final['date'] = pd.to_datetime(output_df_final, errors='raise', dayfirst=True)
    output_df_final['date'] = output_df_final['date'].apply(pd.to_datetime)


    return(output_df_final)
    

test = filter_event(input_data = df
                    , input_variable_name = 'event'
                    , input_delta_time_threshold_seconds = 60
                    )
```

**What the final DF should look like**

```
final_df
Out[20]: 
                 date  event
0 2019-05-10 12:20:31      1
1 2019-05-10 12:28:00      0
2 2019-05-10 12:30:01      1
3 2019-05-10 12:40:00      0
4 2019-05-10 12:45:00      1
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use a mask:

```
mask = df['date'].diff().lt('60s')
df[~(mask|mask.shift(-1))]
```

and if you want to ensure swapping of the events:

```
mask = df['date'].diff().lt('60s')
df[~(mask|mask.shift(-1))][lambda d: d['event'].ne(d['event'].shift())]
```

output:

```
                  date  event
0  2019-05-10 12:20:31      1
3  2019-05-10 12:28:00      0
4  2019-05-10 12:30:01      1
9  2019-05-10 12:40:00      0
10 2019-05-10 12:45:00      1
```

Comment: Not-less-than rather than greater-equal to avoid the fillna is a nice touch :)

Comment: thanks @Cimbali , also I realize I had forgotten the swapping condition :p

Answer (score 0):

With `.diff()` we can get the difference in timestamps and remove those less than 60 seconds apart:

```
>>> delay = df['date'].diff().dt.total_seconds()
>>> df_min60s = df[delay.fillna(np.inf).ge(60) & delay.shift(-1).fillna(np.inf).ge(60)]
>>> df_min60s
                  date  event
0  2019-05-10 12:20:31      1
3  2019-05-10 12:28:00      0
4  2019-05-10 12:30:01      1
8  2019-05-10 12:37:00      1
9  2019-05-10 12:40:00      0
10 2019-05-10 12:45:00      1
```

Then we can remove repeated events:

```
>>> df_final = df_min60s[df_min60s['event'].ne(df_min60s['event'].shift())]
>>> df_final
                  date  event
0  2019-05-10 12:20:31      1
3  2019-05-10 12:28:00      0
4  2019-05-10 12:30:01      1
9  2019-05-10 12:40:00      0
10 2019-05-10 12:45:00      1
```

Comment: The reason the 0 is kept at 12:28 instead of 12:25, is that the opening (0) at 12:25:43 is proceeded by closing (1) at 12:25:57, which is less than 60s. Therefore, these two events are false measurements. Hence, we keep the 12:28, as this is the next real opening event. I hope this makes sense.

Comment: Ah I see @CairanVanRooyen you delete pairs of events, not single events. I’ll adjust.

Comment: Indeed, the 'default' position is closed. If we find the device opens (0) and then closes (1) less than 60seconds later, then the opening and closing measurements are false.

Comment: OK @CairanVanRooyen, noted. Can the device reopen less than 60s after its last closing? (So the gap between one valid open-close pair and the next would be less than 60?)

Comment: The device might reopen less than 60s after closing, and we want to ignore that too. So sometimes the device will measure a bunch of opening, closing, opening, closing events within seconds of eachother, and i need the code to ignore all of the events where they are less than 60seconds apart.